# Teradata Python module show table statement does not work

Tags: python, sql, teradata, ddl

I am experimenting with [Teradata-Python module](http://developer.teradata.com/tools/reference/teradata-python-module) and I am new to python

I am trying to fetch table ddl with the help of SHOW TABLE statement and it behaves weird and only returns a few words out of whole DDL. Please see my attempt and error below

```
import teradata
class DB():
    def __init__(self):
        udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="test", version="1.0",logConsole=False)
        session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="tddemo",username="dbc", password="dbc")
        self.session = session

    def fun1(self):
        # session.execute("create table financial.dummytable1(a varchar(10))")
        rows = self.session.execute("SHOW TABLE financial.dummytable1")
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
db = DB()
db.fun1()

print("---The End---")
```

Here is the unexpected result

```
PRIMARY INDEX ( a );]HARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)CK ,
---The End---
```

The desired result

```
CREATE SET TABLE financial.dummytable1 ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      a VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)
PRIMARY INDEX ( a );
---The End---
```

Please help me understand whats going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue for Teradata's Python module. You can see in the comments on the [Teradata Python Module](http://developer.teradata.com/tools/reference/teradata-python-module#ExecuteParameters) page where someone runs into the exact same problem. Thankfully they identified the solution and gave us a workaround a few comments later:

> The reason the results of SHOW TABLE were not displayed properly on
>   the terminal is because the newline characters in the result were
>   mostly likely carriage returns instead of line feeds.  To ensure it
>   displays correctly, you can split the output based on the presence of
>   any newline sequence and print the lines individually.  E.g.

```
import re
for line in re.split("\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n", row[0]):
    print(line)
```

There's some other gotcha's that are captured in there too. Seems like a good thread to bookmark.

Comment: Wow. Love SOF ... Never expected an answer to this. Took a few minutes to write the exact required code which is here        ...                                                                                                         rows = self.session.execute("SHOW TABLE financial.dummytable1")
        for row in rows:
            for line in re.split("\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n", row[0]):
                print(line)